# $f(x) = a_1^x + a_2 ^x +... + a_n^x$ is increasing and $a_1a_2...a_n = 1$

Tags: functions, contest-math, exponential-function

I have encountered this problem in an Olympiad material provided by my teacher and I do not know how to deal with it.
If $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n > 0$ and $a_1a_2...a_n = 1$, prove the function $f:[0, \infty] \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = a_1^x + a_2 ^ x + ... + a_n ^ x$ is increasing. One of my friends managed to solve it using derivatives, but I would like an approach which does not involve calculus, since it is a 10th grade problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $x>y$, then $$f(x)-f(y)=\sum_j{a_j^y(a_j^{x-y}-1)}$$  By AM-GM, $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_j{a_j^{x-y}}\geq\sqrt[n]{\prod_j{a_j^{x-y}}}=\left(\prod_j{a_j}\right)^{\frac{x-y}{n}}=1$$  Thus $$\sum_j{a_j^{x-y}}\geq n$$  Finally, let $a_m$ be the $a_j$ of smallest magnitude.  Then $$f(x)-f(y)=\sum_j{a_j^y(a_j^{x-y}-1)}\geq a_m^y\sum_j{(a_j^{x-y}-1)}=a_m^y\left(\left(\sum_j{a_j^{x-y}}\right)-n\right)\geq0$$